# C# : Redirect console application output : How to flush the output?

Tags: c#, console, external-process, output-redirect

I am spawning external console application and use async output redirect.
[as shown in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442680/best-way-to-interact-with-command-line-application)

My problem is it seems that the spawned process needs to produce certain amount of output before I get the **OutputDataReceived** event notification.

I want to receive the **OutputDataReceived** event as soon as possible.

I have a bare-bones redirecting application, and here are some observations:
1. When I call a simple 'while(true) print("X");' console application (C#) I receive output event immediately.
2. When I call a 3d party app I am trying to wrap **from the command line** I see the line-by-line output.
3. When I call that 3d party app from my bare-bone wrapper (see 1) - the output comes in chunks (about one page size).

What happens inside that app?

FYI: The app in question is a "USBee DX Data Exctarctor (Async bus) v1.0".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did some more research and have a fix to microsofts Process class. But as my last answer was deleted without a reason, I have had to create a new one.

So take this example...

Create a windows app and stick a rich textbox on the main form, then add this to the form load...

```
        Process p = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                ErrorDialog = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
            },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true,
            SynchronizingObject = this
        };

        p.OutputDataReceived += (s, ea) => this.richTextBox1.AppendText(ea.Data);

        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

This will output something like this...

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

The OutputDataReceived event is not fired for the last line. After some ILSpying it appears that this is deliberate because the last line does not end with a crlf, it assumes there is more comming and appends it to the start of the next event.

To correct this, I have written a wrapper for the Process class and taken some of the required internal classes out with it so that it all works neatly. Here is the FixedProcess class...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace System.Diagnostics
{
    internal delegate void UserCallBack(string data);
    public delegate void DataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e);

    public class FixedProcess : Process
    {
        internal AsyncStreamReader output;
        internal AsyncStreamReader error;
        public event DataReceivedEventHandler OutputDataReceived;
        public event DataReceivedEventHandler ErrorDataReceived;

        public new void BeginOutputReadLine()
        {
            Stream baseStream = StandardOutput.BaseStream;
            this.output = new AsyncStreamReader(this, baseStream, new UserCallBack(this.FixedOutputReadNotifyUser), StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding);
            this.output.BeginReadLine();
        }

        public void BeginErrorReadLine()
        {
            Stream baseStream = StandardError.BaseStream;
            this.error = new AsyncStreamReader(this, baseStream, new UserCallBack(this.FixedErrorReadNotifyUser), StandardError.CurrentEncoding);
            this.error.BeginReadLine();
        }

        internal void FixedOutputReadNotifyUser(string data)
        {
            DataReceivedEventHandler outputDataReceived = this.OutputDataReceived;
            if (outputDataReceived != null)
            {
                DataReceivedEventArgs dataReceivedEventArgs = new DataReceivedEventArgs(data);
                if (this.SynchronizingObject != null && this.SynchronizingObject.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.SynchronizingObject.Invoke(outputDataReceived, new object[]
                    {
                        this, 
                        dataReceivedEventArgs
                    });
                    return;
                }
                outputDataReceived(this, dataReceivedEventArgs);
            }
        }

        internal void FixedErrorReadNotifyUser(string data)
        {
            DataReceivedEventHandler errorDataReceived = this.ErrorDataReceived;
            if (errorDataReceived != null)
            {
                DataReceivedEventArgs dataReceivedEventArgs = new DataReceivedEventArgs(data);
                if (this.SynchronizingObject != null && this.SynchronizingObject.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.SynchronizingObject.Invoke(errorDataReceived, new object[]
                    {
                        this, 
                        dataReceivedEventArgs
                    });
                    return;
                }
                errorDataReceived(this, dataReceivedEventArgs);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class AsyncStreamReader : IDisposable
    {
        internal const int DefaultBufferSize = 1024;
        private const int MinBufferSize = 128;
        private Stream stream;
        private Encoding encoding;
        private Decoder decoder;
        private byte[] byteBuffer;
        private char[] charBuffer;
        private int _maxCharsPerBuffer;
        private Process process;
        private UserCallBack userCallBack;
        private bool cancelOperation;
        private ManualResetEvent eofEvent;
        private Queue messageQueue;
        private StringBuilder sb;
        private bool bLastCarriageReturn;
        public virtual Encoding CurrentEncoding
        {
            get
            {
                return this.encoding;
            }
        }
        public virtual Stream BaseStream
        {
            get
            {
                return this.stream;
            }
        }
        internal AsyncStreamReader(Process process, Stream stream, UserCallBack callback, Encoding encoding)
            : this(process, stream, callback, encoding, 1024)
        {
        }
        internal AsyncStreamReader(Process process, Stream stream, UserCallBack callback, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize)
        {
            this.Init(process, stream, callback, encoding, bufferSize);
            this.messageQueue = new Queue();
        }
        private void Init(Process process, Stream stream, UserCallBack callback, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize)
        {
            this.process = process;
            this.stream = stream;
            this.encoding = encoding;
            this.userCallBack = callback;
            this.decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();
            if (bufferSize < 128)
            {
                bufferSize = 128;
            }
            this.byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            this._maxCharsPerBuffer = encoding.GetMaxCharCount(bufferSize);
            this.charBuffer = new char[this._maxCharsPerBuffer];
            this.cancelOperation = false;
            this.eofEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            this.sb = null;
            this.bLastCarriageReturn = false;
        }
        public virtual void Close()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
        }
        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && this.stream != null)
            {
                this.stream.Close();
            }
            if (this.stream != null)
            {
                this.stream = null;
                this.encoding = null;
                this.decoder = null;
                this.byteBuffer = null;
                this.charBuffer = null;
            }
            if (this.eofEvent != null)
            {
                this.eofEvent.Close();
                this.eofEvent = null;
            }
        }
        internal void BeginReadLine()
        {
            if (this.cancelOperation)
            {
                this.cancelOperation = false;
            }
            if (this.sb == null)
            {
                this.sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
                this.stream.BeginRead(this.byteBuffer, 0, this.byteBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(this.ReadBuffer), null);
                return;
            }
            this.FlushMessageQueue();
        }
        internal void CancelOperation()
        {
            this.cancelOperation = true;
        }
        private void ReadBuffer(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            int num;
            try
            {
                num = this.stream.EndRead(ar);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                num = 0;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                num = 0;
            }
            if (num == 0)
            {
                lock (this.messageQueue)
                {
                    if (this.sb.Length != 0)
                    {
                        this.messageQueue.Enqueue(this.sb.ToString());
                        this.sb.Length = 0;
                    }
                    this.messageQueue.Enqueue(null);
                }
                try
                {
                    this.FlushMessageQueue();
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.eofEvent.Set();
                }
            }
            int chars = this.decoder.GetChars(this.byteBuffer, 0, num, this.charBuffer, 0);
            this.sb.Append(this.charBuffer, 0, chars);
            this.GetLinesFromStringBuilder();
            this.stream.BeginRead(this.byteBuffer, 0, this.byteBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(this.ReadBuffer), null);
        }
        private void GetLinesFromStringBuilder()
        {
            int i = 0;
            int num = 0;
            int length = this.sb.Length;
            if (this.bLastCarriageReturn && length > 0 && this.sb[0] == '\n')
            {
                i = 1;
                num = 1;
                this.bLastCarriageReturn = false;
            }
            while (i < length)
        {
            char c = this.sb[i];
            if (c == '\r' || c == '\n')
            {
                if (c == '\r' && i + 1 < length && this.sb[i + 1] == '\n')
                {
                    i++;
                }

                string obj = this.sb.ToString(num, i + 1 - num);

                num = i + 1;

                lock (this.messageQueue)
                {
                    this.messageQueue.Enqueue(obj);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

            // Flush Fix: Send Whatever is left in the buffer
            string endOfBuffer = this.sb.ToString(num, length - num);
            lock (this.messageQueue)
            {
                this.messageQueue.Enqueue(endOfBuffer);
                num = length;
            }
            // End Flush Fix

            if (this.sb[length - 1] == '\r')
            {
                this.bLastCarriageReturn = true;
            }
            if (num < length)
            {
                this.sb.Remove(0, num);
            }
            else
            {
                this.sb.Length = 0;
            }
            this.FlushMessageQueue();
        }
        private void FlushMessageQueue()
        {
            while (this.messageQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                lock (this.messageQueue)
                {
                    if (this.messageQueue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string data = (string)this.messageQueue.Dequeue();
                        if (!this.cancelOperation)
                        {
                            this.userCallBack(data);
                        }
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        internal void WaitUtilEOF()
        {
            if (this.eofEvent != null)
            {
                this.eofEvent.WaitOne();
                this.eofEvent.Close();
                this.eofEvent = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public class DataReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        internal string _data;
        /// <summary>Gets the line of characters that was written to a redirected <see cref="T:System.Diagnostics.Process" /> output stream.</summary>
        /// <returns>The line that was written by an associated <see cref="T:System.Diagnostics.Process" /> to its redirected <see cref="P:System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardOutput" /> or <see cref="P:System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardError" /> stream.</returns>
        /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
        public string Data
        {
            get
            {
                return this._data;
            }
        }
        internal DataReceivedEventArgs(string data)
        {
            this._data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Stick that in your project and then change ...

```
Process p = new Process()
{
    ....
```

to

```
FixedProcess p = new FixedProcess()
{
    ....
```

Now your application should display something like this...

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Projects\FixedProcess\bin\Debug>
```

without needing to make any other changes to your existing code. It is also still async and wrapped up nicely. The one caveat is that now you will get multiple events for large output with potential breaks in-between, so you will need to handle this scenario yourself. Other than that, it should be all good.

Comment: "The one caveat is that now you will get multiple events for large output with potential breaks in-between" - How exactly would that be a problem? I just added a `StringBuilder.Append()` to the `OutputDataReceived` event.

Comment: This method occasionally gives me empty output on short program runs, btw... is there a way to wait for the async process to fully catch up before processing the final value?

Comment: On that note, shouldn't this also override the `Exited` event to wait for the async operations?

Comment: This extended class has one big advantage: It adds `\r\n` to output data chunks read via `OutputDataReceived ` events. This enables a proper line handling of the redirected output.

Comment: After searching too many answers landed up here and it worked  Thanks @dean nort

Answer (score 2):

It seems as the problem was that the dummy app was written in c# which flushes the output automatically one every println while the 3rd party app was written in c/c++ and therefore only wrote when the stdoutbuffer was full. The only solution which ive found is to make sure the c/c++ app flushes after every print or to set its buffer to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer.

[How to send input to the console as if the user is typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451228/how-to-send-input-to-the-console-as-if-the-user-is-typing/451986#451986)

The idea is that you will receive the output received events when any is thrown after the process is started.