# Run npm init from the c# console app

Tags: c#, node.js, npm, console-application

I have try to run "npm init" command from the c# console app, using this code:

```
private void Execute(string command, string arg)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = command;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"E:\Work\";  
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }

    Execute(@"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd", "init");
```

But nothing happening. I getting only 2 empty lines after the running my app. Please, help to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at my example of running the `npm run dist` command.

```
var psiNpmRunDist = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    WorkingDirectory = guiProjectDirectory
};
var pNpmRunDist = Process.Start(psiNpmRunDist);
pNpmRunDist.StandardInput.WriteLine("npm run dist & exit");
pNpmRunDist.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I got an edit suggestion from @stefan.seeland with a comment:
"An 'System.InvalidOperationException' gets thrown without setting UseShellExecute"  
It has been rejected by two other users. I am using .NET Core 1.1 and I don't get the exception. Anyone gets the exception without UseShellExecute in .NET Framework or other Core versions, or even (but I doubt) in this version?

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me:

```
private static string RunCommand(string commandToRun, string workingDirectory = null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(workingDirectory))
    {
        workingDirectory = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    }

    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "cmd",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
    };

    var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

    if (process == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Process should not be null.");
    }

    process.StandardInput.WriteLine($"{commandToRun} & exit");
    process.WaitForExit();

    var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    return output;
}
```

You would use this like so:

```
var initResult = RunCommand("npm run init", @"E:\Work\");
```

This works for dotnet core as well as the standard .net framework.

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved this problem like this:

```
foreach (string s in commands)
{
   proc = Process.Start("npm.cmd", s);
   proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to capture the Process.StandardOutput: [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)

Like this:

```
p.Start();

// To avoid deadlocks, always read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Although, since NPM can be a long running process, you may want to wire up an event handler like in these samples: [Realtime Console Output Redirection using Process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2332127/1186321)

Comment: does anything get populated in the 'output' variable?

Comment: 'output' variable is empty. Actually process are freezes at p.Start() code.

Answer (score 0):

`npm init` prompts for several user inputs on a new project. For example, the project name, version, author, etc. These values are expected on `StandardInput`. You are correctly redirecting `StandardInput`, but I do not see you providing these values here. NPM will block until it receives this input, which is likely why you are seeing the application freeze. You will need to use `WriteLine` to provide the answers to NPM's questions in order to move forward, or at a minimum a blank `WriteLine` for each question will suffice. You can do this by calling `p.StandardInput.WriteLine`.

On my version of NPM (3.8.6), the following questions are asked:

```
name: (foo) 
version: (1.0.0) 
description: 
entry point: (index.js) 
test command: 
git repository: 
keywords: 
author: 
license: (ISC)
```

In addition to this, NPM will prompt with an "Are you sure?" at the end.