# Reliably kill node.js process launched via cmd process in a .NET Core app

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, cmd, .net-core

## What am I trying to solve

To improve my build pipeline, I'd like to add an end-to-end test step. I'm planning to achieve it by means of a CLI tool (.NET "Console App"). The tool will spin up and orchestrate a few `npm`/`node` commands (processes).

More specifically, there will be:

1. a back-end process;
2. a front-end process;
3. and a test process.

When a test process (`3`) completes, the CLI tool should terminate back-end (`1`) and front-end (`2`) processes gracefully, plus return `0` exit code if **every** orchestrated process has successfully terminated.

## Trouble

In my [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) below I'm trying to spin up a process `serviceAlikeProcess` and a failing process (`brokenWithErrorProcess`). When the latter one fails, I'm trying to forcibly terminate the former one via `Kill(process)` method.

**!!!** As it is [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43952716/482868), the `node`/`npm` processes are being launched via `cmd` process. I.e. I'm first spinning up a `cmd` process, and then write `node test.js` to its `stdin` stream. The `node` process gets launched just fine but when the `cmd` process is terminated later, the `node` process keeps running and producing the output.

*I suppose this happens due to the fact `cmd` and `node` processes are not getting linked in a parent-child relationship* (because if I manually terminate the `cmd` process from a Task Manager, I observe same exact behavior).

## Question

**How do I reliably kill both processes?**

**Idea:** I was thinking about capturing the `node` process' `pid` and then terminate both `cmd` and `node` processes myself, but I haven't found a way to capture that `pid`...

## Code

#### Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace RunE2E
{
    public class Program
    {
        static string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceAlikeProcess = StartProcessViaCmd("node", "test.js", "");


            var brokenWithErrorProcess = StartProcessViaCmd("npm", "THIS IS NOT A REAL COMMAND, THEREFORE EXPECTED TO FAIL", "");
            brokenWithErrorProcess.Exited += (_, __) => KillProcess(serviceAlikeProcess);


            serviceAlikeProcess.WaitForExit();
            return serviceAlikeProcess.ExitCode;
        }

        private static Process StartProcessViaCmd(string command, string arguments, string workingDirectory)
        {
            workingDirectory = NormalizeWorkingDirectory(workingDirectory);

            var process = new Process
            {
                EnableRaisingEvents = true,
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd",
                    Arguments = arguments,
                    WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
            };

            process.ErrorDataReceived += (_, e) => handle(command, arguments, workingDirectory, "ERROR", e.Data);
            process.OutputDataReceived += (_, e) => handle(command, arguments, workingDirectory, "OUTPUT", e.Data);

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{workingDirectory}] {command} {arguments}");

                var _ = process.Start();

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine($"{command} {arguments} & exit");
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{workingDirectory}] {command} {arguments} : {exc}");
                throw;
            }
            return process;
        }

        static string NormalizeWorkingDirectory(string workingDirectory)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(workingDirectory))
                return currentDirectory;
            else if (Path.IsPathRooted(workingDirectory))
                return workingDirectory;
            else
                return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, workingDirectory));
        }

        static Action<string, string, string, string, string> handle =
            (string command, string arguments, string workingDirectory, string level, string message) =>
            Console.WriteLine($"[{workingDirectory}] {command} {arguments} {level}: {message}");

        static void KillProcess(Process process)
        {
            if (process != null && !process.HasExited)
                process.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

#### test.js

```
setInterval(() => {
    console.info(new Date());
}, 1000);
```

## Screenshots

#### Before launching any processes programmatically

[image]

#### After the `cmd` process is killed

[image]

#### Console output

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really *really* don't like ending up answering my own question(s), especially when the answer is based on a hack-ish way of achieving the results.

However, I understand that this may save somebody else their time. So, here's my solution:

## Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace RunE2E
{
    public class Program
    {
        static string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceAlikeProcessResult = StartProcessViaCmd("node", "test.js", "");
            var serviceAlikeProcess = serviceAlikeProcessResult.MainProcess;

            var brokenWithErrorResult = StartProcessViaCmd("npm", "THIS IS NOT A REAL COMMAND, THEREFORE EXPECTED TO FAIL", "");
            var brokenWithErrorProcess = brokenWithErrorResult.MainProcess;
            brokenWithErrorProcess.Exited += (_, __) =>
            {
                KillProcesses("Front-End", serviceAlikeProcessResult.MainProcess, serviceAlikeProcessResult.CreatedProcesses);
                KillProcesses("E2E-Test", brokenWithErrorResult.MainProcess, brokenWithErrorResult.CreatedProcesses);
            };

            serviceAlikeProcess.WaitForExit();
            return serviceAlikeProcess.ExitCode;
        }

        private static CommandStartResult StartProcessViaCmd(string command, string arguments, string workingDirectory)
        {
            workingDirectory = NormalizeWorkingDirectory(workingDirectory);

            var process = new Process
            {
                EnableRaisingEvents = true,
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd",
                    Arguments = arguments,
                    WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                },
            };
            var createdProcesses = new List<Process>();

            process.ErrorDataReceived += (_, e) => handle(command, arguments, workingDirectory, "ERROR", e.Data);
            process.OutputDataReceived += (_, e) => handle(command, arguments, workingDirectory, "", e.Data);

            var commandId = $"[{workingDirectory}] {command} {arguments}";
            try
            {
                WriteLine(commandId);

                createdProcesses = StartProcessAndCapture(commandId, process);

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine($"{command} {arguments} & exit");
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                WriteLine($"{commandId}: {exc}");
                throw;
            }

            return new CommandStartResult
            {
                MainProcess = process,
                CreatedProcesses = createdProcesses,
            };
        }

        static List<Process> StartProcessAndCapture(string commandId, Process processToStart)
        {
            var before = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
            var beforePidSet = new HashSet<int>(before.Select(process => process.Id));

            var _ = processToStart.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            var after = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
            var newlyCreatedProcessIdList = new HashSet<int>(after.Select(process => process.Id));
            newlyCreatedProcessIdList.ExceptWith(beforePidSet);
            var createdProcesses = after.Where(process => newlyCreatedProcessIdList.Contains(process.Id)).ToList();

            foreach (var process in createdProcesses)
                WriteLine($"{commandId} ||| [{process.Id}] {process.ProcessName}", ConsoleColor.Blue);

            return createdProcesses;
        }

        static string NormalizeWorkingDirectory(string workingDirectory)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(workingDirectory))
                return currentDirectory;
            else if (Path.IsPathRooted(workingDirectory))
                return workingDirectory;
            else
                return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, workingDirectory));
        }

        static Action<string, string, string, string, string> handle =
            (string command, string arguments, string workingDirectory, string level, string message) =>
            {
                var defaultColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
                Write($"[{workingDirectory}] ");
                Write($"{command} ", ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
                Write($"{arguments}", ConsoleColor.Green);
                Write($"{level} ", level == "" ? defaultColor : ConsoleColor.Red);
                WriteLine($": {message}");
            };

        static void KillProcesses(string prefix, Process baseProcess, List<Process> processList)
        {
            processList = baseProcess == null ?
                processList :
                processList.Where(process => process.Id != baseProcess.Id).Append(baseProcess).ToList();

            foreach (var process in processList)
                KillProcess(prefix, process);
        }

        static void KillProcess(string prefix, Process process)
        {
            if (process != null && !process.HasExited)
                try
                {
                    WriteLine(prefix + " | Kill (" + process.ProcessName + ") [" + process.Id + "]");
                    process.Kill();
                }
                catch (Win32Exception win32exc)
                {
                    WriteLine(prefix + " | Kill (" + process.ProcessName + ") [" + process.Id + "]: " + win32exc.Message);
                }
        }

        static void WaitForExit(Process process)
        {
            while (process.HasExited == false) { }
        }

        static object console = new object();
        static void Write(string text, ConsoleColor? color = null)
        {
            lock (console)
            {
                var original = Console.ForegroundColor;
                Console.ForegroundColor = color.HasValue ? color.Value : original;
                Console.Write(text);
                Console.ForegroundColor = original;
            }
        }
        static void WriteLine(string text = null, ConsoleColor? color = null)
        {
            lock (console)
            {
                var original = Console.ForegroundColor;
                Console.ForegroundColor = color.HasValue ? color.Value : original;
                Console.WriteLine(text);
                Console.ForegroundColor = original;
            }
        }
    }

    class CommandStartResult
    {
        public Process MainProcess { get; set; }
        public List<Process> CreatedProcesses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Additionally, one may want to use the following methods when dealing with .NET Core processes.

```
        private static CommandStartResult StartDotnetProcess(string arguments, string workingDirectory)
        {
            var command = "dotnet";
            workingDirectory = NormalizeWorkingDirectory(workingDirectory);

            var process = PrepareProcess(command, arguments, workingDirectory);
            var createdProcesses = new List<Process>();
            var commandId = $"[{workingDirectory}] {command} {arguments}";
            try
            {
                WriteLine(commandId);

                createdProcesses = StartProcessAndCapture(commandId, process);

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                WriteLine($"{commandId} : {exc}");
                throw;
            }

            return new CommandStartResult
            {
                MainProcess = process,
                CreatedProcesses = createdProcesses,
            };
        }

        private static Process PrepareProcess(
            string command,
            string arguments,
            string workingDirectory
        )
        {
            var process = new Process
            {
                EnableRaisingEvents = true,
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = command,
                    Arguments = arguments,
                    WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                },
            };

            process.ErrorDataReceived += (_, e) => handle(command, arguments, workingDirectory, "ERROR", e.Data);
            process.OutputDataReceived += (_, e) => handle(command, arguments, workingDirectory, "", e.Data);

            process.StartInfo.Environment.Add("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Development");

            return process;
        }
```