# E2E test orchestration with Gulp on Windows: Unable to kill process(es)

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, process, gulp

## What I'm trying to achieve

This question is related to [another one I recently closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908369/reliably-kill-node-js-process-launched-via-cmd-process-in-a-net-core-app) with a horrible hack™.

> I am trying to write a script that can be used a step in a context of a **CI/build pipeline**.
>
> The script is supposed to run Protractor-based end-to-end tests for our Angular single-page application (SPA).
>
> The script is required to do the following actions (in order):
>
> 1. run a .NET Core microservice called "App"
> 2. run a .NET Core microservice called "Web"
> 3. run the SPA
> 4. run a command that executes Protractor tests
> 5. after steps 4 is complete (either successfully or with an error), terminate processes created on steps 1-3. This is **absolutely necessary** otherwise the build will never finish in CI and/or there will be zombie Web/App/SPA processes which will break future build pipeline execution.

## The issue

I haven't started working on step 4 ("e2e test") because I really want to make sure that the step 5 ("cleanup") works as intended.

As you could guess (right), **the cleanup step does not work. Specifically, the processes "App" and "Web" do not get killed for some reason and continue running.**

BTW, I made sure that my gulp script is executed with elevated (admin) privileges.

### Issue - UPDATE 1

I have just discovered the direct cause of the issue (I think), I don't know what's the *root cause* though. There are 5 processes launched instead of 1 as I was expecting. E.g., for `App` process the following processes are observed in Process manager:

```
{                          
  "id": 14840,             
  "binary": "cmd.exe",     
  "title": "Console"       
},                         
{                          
  "id": 12600,             
  "binary": "dotnet.exe",  
  "title": "Console"       
},                         
{                          
  "id": 12976,             
  "binary": "cmd.exe",     
  "title": "Console"       
},                         
{                          
  "id": 5492,              
  "binary": "cmd.exe",     
  "title": "Console"       
},                         
{                          
  "id": 2636,              
  "binary": "App.exe",
  "title": "Console"       
}
```

Similarly, five processes rather than one are created for `Web` service:

```
{                          
  "id": 13264,             
  "binary": "cmd.exe",     
  "title": "Console"       
},                         
{                          
  "id": 1900,              
  "binary": "dotnet.exe",  
  "title": "Console"       
},                         
{                          
  "id": 4668,              
  "binary": "cmd.exe",     
  "title": "Console"       
},                         
{                          
  "id": 15520,             
  "binary": "Web.exe",
  "title": "Console"       
},                         
{                          
  "id": 7516,              
  "binary": "cmd.exe",     
  "title": "Console"       
}
```

## How I am doing that

Basically, the work horse here is the `runCmdAndListen()` function that spins off the processes by running the `cmd` provided as an argument. When the function launches a process be the means of Node.js's `exec()`, it is then pushed to the `createdProcesses` array for tracking.

The Gulp step called `CLEANUP = "cleanup"` is responsible for iterating through the `createdProcesses` and invoking `.kill('SIGTERM')` on each of them, which is supposed to kill all the processes created earlier.

## `gulpfile.js` (Gulp task script)

### Imports and constants

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const path = require('path');

const RUN_APP = `run-app`;
const RUN_WEB = `run-web`;
const RUN_SPA = `run-spa`;
const CLEANUP = `cleanup`;

const appDirectory = path.join(`..`, `App`);
const webDirectory = path.join(`..`, `Web`);
const spaDirectory = path.join(`.`);

const createdProcesses = [];
```

### `runCmdAndListen()`

```
/**
 * Runs a command and taps on `stdout` waiting for a `resolvePhrase` if provided.
 * @param {*} name Title of the process to use in console output.
 * @param {*} command Command to execute.
 * @param {*} cwd Command working directory.
 * @param {*} env Command environment parameters.
 * @param {*} resolvePhrase Phrase to wait for in `stdout` and resolve on.
 * @param {*} rejectOnError Flag showing whether to reject on a message in `stderr` or not.
 */
function runCmdAndListen(name, command, cwd, env, resolvePhrase, rejectOnError) {

  const options = { cwd };
  if (env) options.env = env;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const newProcess = exec(command, options);

    console.info(`Adding a running process with id ${newProcess.pid}`);
    createdProcesses.push({ childProcess: newProcess, isRunning: true });

    newProcess.on('exit', () => {
      createdProcesses
        .find(({ childProcess, _ }) => childProcess.pid === newProcess.pid)
        .isRunning = false;
    });

    newProcess.stdout
      .on(`data`, chunk => {
        if (resolvePhrase && chunk.toString().indexOf(resolvePhrase) >= 0) {
          console.info(`RESOLVED ${name}/${resolvePhrase}`);
          resolve();
        }
      });

    newProcess.stderr
      .on(`data`, chunk => {
        if (rejectOnError) reject(chunk);
      });

    if (!resolvePhrase) {
      console.info(`RESOLVED ${name}`);
      resolve();
    }
  });
}
```

### Basic Gulp tasks

```
gulp.task(RUN_APP, () => runCmdAndListen(
  `[App]`,
  `dotnet run --no-build --no-dependencies`,
  appDirectory,
  { 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT': `Development` },
  `Now listening on:`,
  true)
);

gulp.task(RUN_WEB, () => runCmdAndListen(
  `[Web]`,
  `dotnet run --no-build --no-dependencies`,
  webDirectory,
  { 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT': `Development` },
  `Now listening on:`,
  true)
);

gulp.task(RUN_SPA, () => runCmdAndListen(
  `[SPA]`,
  `npm run start-prodish-for-e2e`,
  spaDirectory,
  null,
  `webpack: Compiled successfully
  `,
  false)
);

gulp.task(CLEANUP, () => {
  createdProcesses
    .forEach(({ childProcess, isRunning }) => {
      console.warn(`Killing child process ${childProcess.pid}`);

      // if (isRunning) {
      childProcess.kill('SIGTERM');
      // }
    });
});
```

### The orchestrating task

```
gulp.task(
  'e2e',
  gulp.series(
    gulp.series(
      RUN_APP,
      RUN_WEB,
    ),
    RUN_SPA,
    CLEANUP,
  ),
  () => console.info(`All tasks complete`),
);

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('e2e'));
```

Comment: Have you tried to kill all processes with title `Console`?

Comment: @oleksii, yes I have and it worked. The issue is that I don't have a reliable precise way of getting the list of those processes programmaticaly.

Comment: Do you think about Docker?

Comment: @Oleksii not really. My team has no sufficient headcount or expertise. The infrastructure is also not quite under our direct control. (I work for gov and bureaucracy is thriving here...)

Comment: What about just `pkill -f Console`? :)

Comment: @Oleksii I don't know WHAT to kill at runtime. That is the problem

Comment: I don't have a precise list of processes on hand nor the way to discover such list.

Comment: This seems to be the root case: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6122

Comment: Try to add `--no-restore` flag to `dotnet run`

Comment: @alex thanks, I'll check it out not later than on Monday

Answer (score 1):

- `dotnet run` does not propagate the kill signal to children in Windows (that's the behavior in Windows, which differs in POSIX OS), you're doing the right thing, which is to manage the children processes
- however `SIGTERM` won't work on windows: [nodejs doc process_signal_events](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events); that's your problem. You might want to try `SIGKILL`.
- for a pure js solution, just `process.kill(process.pid, SIGKILL)` though, this might need to be tested: [nodejs issue 12378](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12378).
- for a reliable MSFT tested solution (but not cross-platform), consider powershell to manage trees thanks to the following powershell functions:

  ```
  function startproc($mydotnetcommand)
  {
      $parentprocid = Start-Process $mydotnetcommand -passthru
  }

  function stopproctree($parentprocid)
  {
      $childpidlist= Get-WmiObject win32_process |`
          where {$_.ParentProcessId -eq $parentprocid}
      Get-Process -Id $childpidlist -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |`
          Stop-Process -Force
  }
  ```

  You can use the 2nd function from the outside of the ps script through passing parent PID as argument to the `stopproctree` function with:

  ```
  param([Int32]$parentprocid)
  stopproctree $parentprocid
  ```

  (in the script, say treecleaner.ps1), and then `powershell.exe -file treecleaner.ps1 -parentprocid XXX`

Comment: I'm really trying to avoid any new technologies on top of bash/gulp/Node.js and .NET Core. Can I achieve the same without powershell?

Comment: Roughly yes, but anything else would take much more code. You can see powershell as a simple wrap of a dotnet system library, or as an object oriented bash + gnu tools. What is your motivation about "avoiding new technologies" ? I understood you're in a Windows OS, is it ?

Comment: my motivation is entirely based on a huge burden in terms of number of technologies already existing for a small team in our current project. I.e. nobody knows powershell, and have no time to pick it up. Not everyone even know gulp which we use for running the test suite.

Comment: I understand the argument for a big project, however in this very case, it's actually few lines already written, it cannot be simpler ie., it's the right tech.

Comment: I get what you're saying but our team does not just count the number of lines. We measure the risks from the a) maintenance; b) cross-tech integration risk standpoints.

Comment: I understand. Do you need this to run on POSIX ? You also can translate the powershell script into c#.

Comment: OK. I understand that you want to do everything from js, isn't it ? Can you first check that your gulp function is getting the right children PID ? You may use process explorer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) or the powershell `Get-WmiObject win32_process | where {$_.ParentProcessId -eq $parentprocid}`

Comment: I am not accepting the answer because it does not solve my issue. But you pointed out the root cause of the problem, and I am awarding you the bounty. Thank you for your efforts Soleil!

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Thanks. So, `SIGKILL` doesn't kill the children processes ?