# C# redirect application output in realtime

Tags: c#, real-time, io-redirection

What I am trying to achieve is real-time(synchronous) redirection.
I tried many options which are already answered in Stackoverflow.
But EVERY answer only suggest async redirection.
The word real-time means when slave process print '~~' to console, then master process application immediately capture this and print '~~' to its console.

Below is current code. Note that, I tried several ways and other approach are commented. And I think System.Diagnostics.Process only offer asynchronous stream. Any good solution to achieve synchronous stream in c#?

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "myprocess.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
 };
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
process.OutputDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
};
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();

/* Below is other approach, which do not use DataReceivedEventHandler
string line;
do
{
    line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    // non-thread approach is also tried.
    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate ()
    {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    });
    thread.isBackGround = true;
    thread.Start();
} while (line != null);
*/
```

Comment: What's wrong with the asynchronous approach? You can block and wait for the event to arrive, making it synchronous.

Comment: Related: [Realtime Console Output Redirection using Process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2332127/5265292)

Comment: @zmbq biggest problem is i have to wait til 'slave' exit. Async event is called when 'slave' exited.

Comment: The slave should probably flush its output.

Comment: @zmbq yep flush was key problem. When I change slave to flush immediately then this code capture in real-time thanks very much zmbq. :)