# Code conversion from c# to vb.net including eventhandlers

Tags: c#, vb.net, event-handling, raiseevent

Hello I have found a great class written in c# which I would like to use in a VB.NET project.

I found it in this thread:
[C# : Redirect console application output : How to flush the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033648/c-sharp-redirect-console-application-output-how-to-flush-the-output)

The C# Class
looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace System.Diagnostics
{
    internal delegate void UserCallBack(string data);
    public delegate void DataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e);

    public class FixedProcess : Process
    {
        internal AsyncStreamReader output;
        internal AsyncStreamReader error;
        public event DataReceivedEventHandler OutputDataReceived;
        public event DataReceivedEventHandler ErrorDataReceived;

        public new void BeginOutputReadLine()
        {
            Stream baseStream = StandardOutput.BaseStream;
            this.output = new AsyncStreamReader(this, baseStream, new UserCallBack(this.FixedOutputReadNotifyUser), StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding);
            this.output.BeginReadLine();
        }

        public void BeginErrorReadLine()
        {
            Stream baseStream = StandardError.BaseStream;
            this.error = new AsyncStreamReader(this, baseStream, new UserCallBack(this.FixedErrorReadNotifyUser), StandardError.CurrentEncoding);
            this.error.BeginReadLine();
        }

        internal void FixedOutputReadNotifyUser(string data)
        {
            DataReceivedEventHandler outputDataReceived = this.OutputDataReceived;
            if (outputDataReceived != null)
            {
                DataReceivedEventArgs dataReceivedEventArgs = new DataReceivedEventArgs(data);
                if (this.SynchronizingObject != null && this.SynchronizingObject.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.SynchronizingObject.Invoke(outputDataReceived, new object[]
                    {
                        this, 
                        dataReceivedEventArgs
                    });
                    return;
                }
                outputDataReceived(this, dataReceivedEventArgs);
            }
        }

        internal void FixedErrorReadNotifyUser(string data)
        {
            DataReceivedEventHandler errorDataReceived = this.ErrorDataReceived;
            if (errorDataReceived != null)
            {
                DataReceivedEventArgs dataReceivedEventArgs = new DataReceivedEventArgs(data);
                if (this.SynchronizingObject != null && this.SynchronizingObject.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.SynchronizingObject.Invoke(errorDataReceived, new object[]
                    {
                        this, 
                        dataReceivedEventArgs
                    });
                    return;
                }
                errorDataReceived(this, dataReceivedEventArgs);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class AsyncStreamReader : IDisposable
    {
        internal const int DefaultBufferSize = 1024;
        private const int MinBufferSize = 128;
        private Stream stream;
        private Encoding encoding;
        private Decoder decoder;
        private byte[] byteBuffer;
        private char[] charBuffer;
        private int _maxCharsPerBuffer;
        private Process process;
        private UserCallBack userCallBack;
        private bool cancelOperation;
        private ManualResetEvent eofEvent;
        private Queue messageQueue;
        private StringBuilder sb;
        private bool bLastCarriageReturn;
        public virtual Encoding CurrentEncoding
        {
            get
            {
                return this.encoding;
            }
        }
        public virtual Stream BaseStream
        {
            get
            {
                return this.stream;
            }
        }
        internal AsyncStreamReader(Process process, Stream stream, UserCallBack callback, Encoding encoding)
            : this(process, stream, callback, encoding, 1024)
        {
        }
        internal AsyncStreamReader(Process process, Stream stream, UserCallBack callback, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize)
        {
            this.Init(process, stream, callback, encoding, bufferSize);
            this.messageQueue = new Queue();
        }
        private void Init(Process process, Stream stream, UserCallBack callback, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize)
        {
            this.process = process;
            this.stream = stream;
            this.encoding = encoding;
            this.userCallBack = callback;
            this.decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();
            if (bufferSize < 128)
            {
                bufferSize = 128;
            }
            this.byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            this._maxCharsPerBuffer = encoding.GetMaxCharCount(bufferSize);
            this.charBuffer = new char[this._maxCharsPerBuffer];
            this.cancelOperation = false;
            this.eofEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            this.sb = null;
            this.bLastCarriageReturn = false;
        }
        public virtual void Close()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
        }
        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && this.stream != null)
            {
                this.stream.Close();
            }
            if (this.stream != null)
            {
                this.stream = null;
                this.encoding = null;
                this.decoder = null;
                this.byteBuffer = null;
                this.charBuffer = null;
            }
            if (this.eofEvent != null)
            {
                this.eofEvent.Close();
                this.eofEvent = null;
            }
        }
        internal void BeginReadLine()
        {
            if (this.cancelOperation)
            {
                this.cancelOperation = false;
            }
            if (this.sb == null)
            {
                this.sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
                this.stream.BeginRead(this.byteBuffer, 0, this.byteBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(this.ReadBuffer), null);
                return;
            }
            this.FlushMessageQueue();
        }
        internal void CancelOperation()
        {
            this.cancelOperation = true;
        }
        private void ReadBuffer(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            int num;
            try
            {
                num = this.stream.EndRead(ar);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                num = 0;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                num = 0;
            }
            if (num == 0)
            {
                lock (this.messageQueue)
                {
                    if (this.sb.Length != 0)
                    {
                        this.messageQueue.Enqueue(this.sb.ToString());
                        this.sb.Length = 0;
                    }
                    this.messageQueue.Enqueue(null);
                }
                try
                {
                    this.FlushMessageQueue();
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.eofEvent.Set();
                }
            }
            int chars = this.decoder.GetChars(this.byteBuffer, 0, num, this.charBuffer, 0);
            this.sb.Append(this.charBuffer, 0, chars);
            this.GetLinesFromStringBuilder();
            this.stream.BeginRead(this.byteBuffer, 0, this.byteBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(this.ReadBuffer), null);
        }
        private void GetLinesFromStringBuilder()
        {
            int i = 0;
            int num = 0;
            int length = this.sb.Length;
            if (this.bLastCarriageReturn && length > 0 && this.sb[0] == '\n')
            {
                i = 1;
                num = 1;
                this.bLastCarriageReturn = false;
            }
            while (i < length)
        {
            char c = this.sb[i];
            if (c == '\r' || c == '\n')
            {
                if (c == '\r' && i + 1 < length && this.sb[i + 1] == '\n')
                {
                    i++;
                }

                string obj = this.sb.ToString(num, i + 1 - num);

                num = i + 1;

                lock (this.messageQueue)
                {
                    this.messageQueue.Enqueue(obj);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

            // Flush Fix: Send Whatever is left in the buffer
            string endOfBuffer = this.sb.ToString(num, length - num);
            lock (this.messageQueue)
            {
                this.messageQueue.Enqueue(endOfBuffer);
                num = length;
            }
            // End Flush Fix

            if (this.sb[length - 1] == '\r')
            {
                this.bLastCarriageReturn = true;
            }
            if (num < length)
            {
                this.sb.Remove(0, num);
            }
            else
            {
                this.sb.Length = 0;
            }
            this.FlushMessageQueue();
        }
        private void FlushMessageQueue()
        {
            while (this.messageQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                lock (this.messageQueue)
                {
                    if (this.messageQueue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string data = (string)this.messageQueue.Dequeue();
                        if (!this.cancelOperation)
                        {
                            this.userCallBack(data);
                        }
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        internal void WaitUtilEOF()
        {
            if (this.eofEvent != null)
            {
                this.eofEvent.WaitOne();
                this.eofEvent.Close();
                this.eofEvent = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public class DataReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        internal string _data;
        /// <summary>Gets the line of characters that was written to a redirected <see cref="T:System.Diagnostics.Process" /> output stream.</summary>
        /// <returns>The line that was written by an associated <see cref="T:System.Diagnostics.Process" /> to its redirected <see cref="P:System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardOutput" /> or <see cref="P:System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardError" /> stream.</returns>
        /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
        public string Data
        {
            get
            {
                return this._data;
            }
        }
        internal DataReceivedEventArgs(string data)
        {
            this._data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

My Converted Code looks like this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading

Namespace System.Diagnostics
    Friend Delegate Sub UserCallBack(data As String)
    Public Delegate Sub DataReceivedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)

    Public Class FixedProcess
        Inherits Process
        Friend output As AsyncStreamReader
        Friend [error] As AsyncStreamReader
        Public Event OutputDataReceived As DataReceivedEventHandler '<----------Error 1
        Public Event ErrorDataReceived As DataReceivedEventHandler '<------------Error 2

        Public Shadows Sub BeginOutputReadLine()
            Dim baseStream As Stream = StandardOutput.BaseStream
            Me.output = New AsyncStreamReader(Me, baseStream, New UserCallBack(AddressOf Me.FixedOutputReadNotifyUser), StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding)
            Me.output.BeginReadLine()
        End Sub

        Public Sub BeginErrorReadLine()   '<-------------Error 3
            Dim baseStream As Stream = StandardError.BaseStream
            Me.[error] = New AsyncStreamReader(Me, baseStream, New UserCallBack(AddressOf Me.FixedErrorReadNotifyUser), StandardError.CurrentEncoding)
            Me.[error].BeginReadLine()
        End Sub

        Friend Sub FixedOutputReadNotifyUser(data As String)

            Dim outputDataReceived As DataReceivedEventHandler = Me.OutputDataReceived '<------------Error 4
            If outputDataReceived IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim dataReceivedEventArgs As New DataReceivedEventArgs(data)
                If Me.SynchronizingObject IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.SynchronizingObject.InvokeRequired Then
                    Me.SynchronizingObject.Invoke(outputDataReceived, New Object() {Me, dataReceivedEventArgs})
                    Return
                End If
                outputDataReceived(Me, dataReceivedEventArgs)
            End If
        End Sub

        Friend Sub FixedErrorReadNotifyUser(data As String)
            Dim errorDataReceived As DataReceivedEventHandler = Me.ErrorDataReceived '<-------------Error 5
            If errorDataReceived IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim dataReceivedEventArgs As New DataReceivedEventArgs(data)
                If Me.SynchronizingObject IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.SynchronizingObject.InvokeRequired Then
                    Me.SynchronizingObject.Invoke(errorDataReceived, New Object() {Me, dataReceivedEventArgs})
                    Return
                End If
                errorDataReceived(Me, dataReceivedEventArgs)
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class

    Friend Class AsyncStreamReader
        Implements IDisposable
        Friend Const DefaultBufferSize As Integer = 1024
        Private Const MinBufferSize As Integer = 128
        Private stream As Stream
        Private encoding As Encoding
        Private decoder As Decoder
        Private byteBuffer As Byte()
        Private charBuffer As Char()
        Private _maxCharsPerBuffer As Integer
        Private process As Process
        Private userCallBack As UserCallBack
        Private cancelOperation As Boolean
        Private eofEvent As ManualResetEvent
        Private messageQueue As Queue
        Private sb As StringBuilder
        Private bLastCarriageReturn As Boolean
        Public Overridable ReadOnly Property CurrentEncoding() As Encoding
            Get
                Return Me.encoding
            End Get
        End Property
        Public Overridable ReadOnly Property BaseStream() As Stream
            Get
                Return Me.stream
            End Get
        End Property
        Friend Sub New(process As Process, stream As Stream, callback As UserCallBack, encoding As Encoding)
            Me.New(process, stream, callback, encoding, 1024)
        End Sub
        Friend Sub New(process As Process, stream As Stream, callback As UserCallBack, encoding As Encoding, bufferSize As Integer)
            Me.Init(process, stream, callback, encoding, bufferSize)
            Me.messageQueue = New Queue()
        End Sub
        Private Sub Init(process As Process, stream As Stream, callback As UserCallBack, encoding As Encoding, bufferSize As Integer)
            Me.process = process
            Me.stream = stream
            Me.encoding = encoding
            Me.userCallBack = callback
            Me.decoder = encoding.GetDecoder()
            If bufferSize < 128 Then
                bufferSize = 128
            End If
            Me.byteBuffer = New Byte(bufferSize - 1) {}
            Me._maxCharsPerBuffer = encoding.GetMaxCharCount(bufferSize)
            Me.charBuffer = New Char(Me._maxCharsPerBuffer - 1) {}
            Me.cancelOperation = False
            Me.eofEvent = New ManualResetEvent(False)
            Me.sb = Nothing
            Me.bLastCarriageReturn = False
        End Sub
        Public Overridable Sub Close()
            Me.Dispose(True)
        End Sub
        Private Sub IDisposable_Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
            Me.Dispose(True)
            GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
        End Sub
        Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
            If disposing AndAlso Me.stream IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.stream.Close()
            End If
            If Me.stream IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.stream = Nothing
                Me.encoding = Nothing
                Me.decoder = Nothing
                Me.byteBuffer = Nothing
                Me.charBuffer = Nothing
            End If
            If Me.eofEvent IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.eofEvent.Close()
                Me.eofEvent = Nothing
            End If
        End Sub
        Friend Sub BeginReadLine()
            If Me.cancelOperation Then
                Me.cancelOperation = False
            End If
            If Me.sb Is Nothing Then
                Me.sb = New StringBuilder(1024)
                Me.stream.BeginRead(Me.byteBuffer, 0, Me.byteBuffer.Length, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Me.ReadBuffer), Nothing)
                Return
            End If
            Me.FlushMessageQueue()
        End Sub
        Friend Sub CancelOperation()  '<------- Error 6
            Me.cancelOperation = True
        End Sub
        Private Sub ReadBuffer(ar As IAsyncResult)
            Dim num As Integer
            Try
                num = Me.stream.EndRead(ar)
            Catch generatedExceptionName As IOException
                num = 0
            Catch generatedExceptionName As OperationCanceledException
                num = 0
            End Try
            If num = 0 Then
                SyncLock Me.messageQueue
                    If Me.sb.Length <> 0 Then
                        Me.messageQueue.Enqueue(Me.sb.ToString())
                        Me.sb.Length = 0
                    End If
                    Me.messageQueue.Enqueue(Nothing)
                End SyncLock
                Try
                    Me.FlushMessageQueue()
                    Return
                Finally
                    Me.eofEvent.[Set]()
                End Try
            End If
            Dim chars As Integer = Me.decoder.GetChars(Me.byteBuffer, 0, num, Me.charBuffer, 0)
            Me.sb.Append(Me.charBuffer, 0, chars)
            Me.GetLinesFromStringBuilder()
            Me.stream.BeginRead(Me.byteBuffer, 0, Me.byteBuffer.Length, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Me.ReadBuffer), Nothing)
        End Sub
        Private Sub GetLinesFromStringBuilder()
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            Dim num As Integer = 0
            Dim length As Integer = Me.sb.Length
            If Me.bLastCarriageReturn AndAlso length > 0 AndAlso Me.sb(0) = ControlChars.Lf Then
                i = 1
                num = 1
                Me.bLastCarriageReturn = False
            End If
            While i < length
                Dim c As Char = Me.sb(i)
                If c = ControlChars.Cr OrElse c = ControlChars.Lf Then
                    If c = ControlChars.Cr AndAlso i + 1 < length AndAlso Me.sb(i + 1) = ControlChars.Lf Then
                        i += 1
                    End If

                    Dim obj As String = Me.sb.ToString(num, i + 1 - num)

                    num = i + 1

                    SyncLock Me.messageQueue
                        Me.messageQueue.Enqueue(obj)
                    End SyncLock
                End If
                i += 1
            End While

            ' Flush Fix: Send Whatever is left in the buffer
            Dim endOfBuffer As String = Me.sb.ToString(num, length - num)
            SyncLock Me.messageQueue
                Me.messageQueue.Enqueue(endOfBuffer)
                num = length
            End SyncLock
            ' End Flush Fix

            If Me.sb(length - 1) = ControlChars.Cr Then
                Me.bLastCarriageReturn = True
            End If
            If num < length Then
                Me.sb.Remove(0, num)
            Else
                Me.sb.Length = 0
            End If
            Me.FlushMessageQueue()
        End Sub
        Private Sub FlushMessageQueue()
            While Me.messageQueue.Count > 0
                SyncLock Me.messageQueue
                    If Me.messageQueue.Count > 0 Then
                        Dim data As String = DirectCast(Me.messageQueue.Dequeue(), String)
                        If Not Me.cancelOperation Then
                            Me.userCallBack(data)
                        End If
                    End If
                    Continue While
                End SyncLock
                Exit While
            End While
        End Sub
        Friend Sub WaitUtilEOF()
            If Me.eofEvent IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.eofEvent.WaitOne()
                Me.eofEvent.Close()
                Me.eofEvent = Nothing
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class DataReceivedEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs
        Friend _data As String
        ''' <summary>Gets the line of characters that was written to a redirected <see cref="T:System.Diagnostics.Process" /> output stream.</summary>
        ''' <returns>The line that was written by an associated <see cref="T:System.Diagnostics.Process" /> to its redirected <see cref="P:System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardOutput" /> or <see cref="P:System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardError" /> stream.</returns>
        ''' <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
        Public ReadOnly Property Data() As String
            Get
                Return Me._data
            End Get
        End Property
        Friend Sub New(data As String)
            Me._data = data
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Error 1-3 seem to be warnings and might actually work
Especially Error 4 and 5 give me a headache "Public Event OutputDataRecieved(sender As Object, e As DataRecievedEventArgs) is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use the RaiseEvent statement to raise an event."

Eventhandlers dont seem to work with any of the code converters I have tried and I am lacking the VB skills to convert it manually.

Is there a friendly soul out there who can properly convert this class so that it actually works?

Thanks a lot!

Roman

Comment: If you don't know VB why bother converting it to VB?  Leave it in a C# project, and reference it from a VB project.  You can have a C# and a VB project in the same solution.

Comment: Compile the class into a .NET assembly. Add the assembly as a reference to your VB.NET project. Enjoy!

Comment: you can use this method instead of converting it. The IL will be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Overloads keyword to the BeginErrorReadLine method signature.

```
 Public Overloads Sub BeginErrorReadLine()   '<-------------Error 3
```

The event declarations need to be declared as Shadows because they otherwise conflict with the base class event declarations.

```
 Public Shadows Event OutputDataReceived As DataReceivedEventHandler '<----------Error 1
```

Then in your FixedOutputReadNotifyUser method, you don't need to check the event handler as you do in C# to see if it is nothing. VB will do that for you. Instead, simply raise it as follows:

```
Friend Sub FixedOutputReadNotifyUser(data As String)
    Dim dataReceivedEventArgs As New DataReceivedEventArgs(data)
    RaiseEvent OutputDataReceived(Me, dataReceivedEventArgs)
End Sub
```

The last issue is the original class uses case sensitivity to differentiate between the "cancelOperation" field and "CancelOperation" method. Best option is to prefix the field with an underscore as follows: `Private _CancelOperation As Boolean` and then fix the corresponding references in the class.

Comment: +1. And this is why I also gave +1 to CaffGeek's answer that says just build the C# into an assembly and then use it from the VB project, which will take a few minutes and requires little knowledge of C#.

Comment: But going through the effort of translating actually increases your understanding of the code you are using and your language along the way. Blindly using someone else's code without thinking through the ramifications is not necessarily a positive.

Comment: @JimWooley, +1 I agree with you that you should always understand code before using it.

Comment: I would really like to thank you all for the answers I have learned from all of them but finally used Jims code suggestions and they work like a charm!

Comment: How do I do that? - Sorry I am new to this Forum.

Comment: Ok changed the green tick  - thats it I assume :)

Comment: Note that the "Shadows" on the events is required in the same way that "new" should be required in the original C# code - with the same warning/error settings the C# code would have resulted in errors also.

Comment: Also, in the FixedOutputReadNotifyUser method, the statement "If outputDataReceived IsNot Nothing Then" is not checking an event, but a local variable set to the backing delegate derived from the event in the previous statement.  It can be useful to check if a variable of a delegate type is nothing.

Answer (score 4):

In your solution, add a new c# project.  Place this c# code in it.

From your vb project, add a reference to the c# project.

You can now make calls to the c# objects from vb.

It's all the same when it's converted to IL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. I only have Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition installed currently. I am just downloading C# Express 2010 as well... Hopefully this wokring with the Express Editions!

Comment: @user1665789, no problem, welcome to Stack Overflow.  If this, or another question, solved your problem, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your "Error 4" & "Error 5", use this instead - note that you need to set the local variable to the hidden VB backing delegate field ending in "Event".  Also note that your test for the local variable being nothing is still valid since we're not checking if an event is nothing, but a local variable of a delegate type - the approach for "Error 5" is exactly the same:

```
Friend Sub FixedOutputReadNotifyUser(ByVal data As String)
    Dim outputDataReceived As DataReceivedEventHandler = Me.OutputDataReceivedEvent
    If outputDataReceived IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dataReceivedEventArgs As New DataReceivedEventArgs(data)
        If Me.SynchronizingObject IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.SynchronizingObject.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.SynchronizingObject.Invoke(outputDataReceived, New Object() { Me, dataReceivedEventArgs })
            Return
        End If
        outputDataReceived(Me, dataReceivedEventArgs)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I am using now. I removed the namespace as I did not know how to inlcude a second namespace in my project and pasted the code into a new Module. Then as suggested in the original c# solution i just changed my "p as new process" to "p as new FixedProcess".

Thanks again for all the suggestions!

You guys rock!

To give you a complete picture of what I am trying to do I am also including the Form Code. I am not considering myself a programmer so please bear with me if it is not as sophisticated as most of you could possible do it. The intention of this is to remote control a SSH session with plink and to automatically execute commands on Cisco Routers.

The code works quite will now with one (hopefully) little flaw left: If I close the underlying plink.exe I would like to also close the input and output streams. So far I could not find out in my "borrowed" class how to do that.

I would like to do it on the close event of the form. It kills the plink.exe process, but if I open the form again for another session, it DOUBLES the output, if i close and reopen once more it Tripples the output...

Any suggestions how to properly close the streams?

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq


Imports System.Collections



Module Module2


    Friend Delegate Sub UserCallBack(ByVal data As String)
    Public Delegate Sub DataReceivedEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)




    Public Class FixedProcess
        Inherits Process
        Friend output As AsyncStreamReader
        Friend [error] As AsyncStreamReader
        Public Shadows Event OutputDataReceived As DataReceivedEventHandler
        Public Shadows Event ErrorDataReceived As DataReceivedEventHandler

        Public CancelAll As Boolean = False

        Public Overloads Sub BeginOutputReadLine()
            Dim baseStream As Stream = StandardOutput.BaseStream
            Me.output = New AsyncStreamReader(Me, baseStream, New UserCallBack(AddressOf Me.FixedOutputReadNotifyUser), StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding)
            Me.output.BeginReadLine()
        End Sub

        Public Overloads Sub BeginErrorReadLine()
            Dim baseStream As Stream = StandardError.BaseStream
            Me.[error] = New AsyncStreamReader(Me, baseStream, New UserCallBack(AddressOf Me.FixedErrorReadNotifyUser), StandardError.CurrentEncoding)
            Me.[error].BeginReadLine()
        End Sub

        Friend Sub FixedOutputReadNotifyUser(ByVal data As String)
            Dim dataReceivedEventArgs As New DataReceivedEventArgs(data)
            RaiseEvent OutputDataReceived(Me, dataReceivedEventArgs)

        End Sub





        Friend Sub FixedErrorReadNotifyUser(ByVal data As String)
            Dim errorDataReceivedEventArgs As New DataReceivedEventArgs(data)
            RaiseEvent ErrorDataReceived(Me, errorDataReceivedEventArgs)

        End Sub




    End Class

    Friend Class AsyncStreamReader
        Implements IDisposable
        Friend Const DefaultBufferSize As Integer = 1024
        Private Const MinBufferSize As Integer = 128
        Private stream As Stream
        Private encoding As Encoding
        Private decoder As Decoder
        Private byteBuffer As Byte()
        Private charBuffer As Char()
        Private _maxCharsPerBuffer As Integer
        Private process As Process
        Private userCallBack As UserCallBack
        Public cancelOperation As Boolean
        Private eofEvent As ManualResetEvent
        Private messageQueue As Queue
        Private sb As StringBuilder
        Private bLastCarriageReturn As Boolean
        Public Overridable ReadOnly Property CurrentEncoding() As Encoding
            Get
                Return Me.encoding
            End Get
        End Property
        Public Overridable ReadOnly Property BaseStream() As Stream
            Get
                Return Me.stream
            End Get
        End Property
        Friend Sub New(ByVal process As Process, ByVal stream As Stream, ByVal callback As UserCallBack, ByVal encoding As Encoding)
            Me.New(process, stream, callback, encoding, 1024)
        End Sub
        Friend Sub New(ByVal process As Process, ByVal stream As Stream, ByVal callback As UserCallBack, ByVal encoding As Encoding, ByVal bufferSize As Integer)
            Me.Init(process, stream, callback, encoding, bufferSize)
            Me.messageQueue = New Queue()
        End Sub
        Private Sub Init(ByVal process As Process, ByVal stream As Stream, ByVal callback As UserCallBack, ByVal encoding As Encoding, ByVal bufferSize As Integer)
            Me.process = process
            Me.stream = stream
            Me.encoding = encoding
            Me.userCallBack = callback
            Me.decoder = encoding.GetDecoder()
            If bufferSize < 128 Then
                bufferSize = 128
            End If
            Me.byteBuffer = New Byte(bufferSize - 1) {}
            Me._maxCharsPerBuffer = encoding.GetMaxCharCount(bufferSize)
            Me.charBuffer = New Char(Me._maxCharsPerBuffer - 1) {}
            Me.cancelOperation = False
            Me.eofEvent = New ManualResetEvent(False)
            Me.sb = Nothing
            Me.bLastCarriageReturn = False
        End Sub
        Public Overridable Sub Close()
            Me.Dispose(True)
        End Sub
        Private Sub IDisposable_Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
            Me.Dispose(True)
            GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
        End Sub
        Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
            If disposing AndAlso Me.stream IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.stream.Close()
            End If
            If Me.stream IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.stream = Nothing
                Me.encoding = Nothing
                Me.decoder = Nothing
                Me.byteBuffer = Nothing
                Me.charBuffer = Nothing
            End If
            If Me.eofEvent IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.eofEvent.Close()
                Me.eofEvent = Nothing
            End If
        End Sub
        Friend Sub BeginReadLine()
            If Me.cancelOperation Then
                Me.cancelOperation = False
            End If
            If Me.sb Is Nothing Then
                Me.sb = New StringBuilder(1024)
                Me.stream.BeginRead(Me.byteBuffer, 0, Me.byteBuffer.Length, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Me.ReadBuffer), Nothing)
                Return
            End If
            Me.FlushMessageQueue()
        End Sub
        Friend Sub _CancelOperation()
            Me.cancelOperation = True
        End Sub
        Private Sub ReadBuffer(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)

            Dim num As Integer

            Try
                num = Me.stream.EndRead(ar)
            Catch generatedExceptionName As IOException
                num = 0
            Catch generatedExceptionName As OperationCanceledException
                num = 0
            End Try
            If num = 0 Then
                SyncLock Me.messageQueue
                    If Me.sb.Length <> 0 Then
                        Me.messageQueue.Enqueue(Me.sb.ToString())
                        Me.sb.Length = 0
                    End If
                    Me.messageQueue.Enqueue(Nothing)
                End SyncLock
                Try
                    Me.FlushMessageQueue()
                    Return
                Finally
                    Me.eofEvent.[Set]()
                End Try
            End If
            Dim chars As Integer = Me.decoder.GetChars(Me.byteBuffer, 0, num, Me.charBuffer, 0)
            Me.sb.Append(Me.charBuffer, 0, chars)
            Me.GetLinesFromStringBuilder()
            Me.stream.BeginRead(Me.byteBuffer, 0, Me.byteBuffer.Length, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Me.ReadBuffer), Nothing)


        End Sub
        Private Sub GetLinesFromStringBuilder()
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            Dim num As Integer = 0
            Dim length As Integer = Me.sb.Length
            If Me.bLastCarriageReturn AndAlso length > 0 AndAlso Me.sb(0) = ControlChars.Lf Then
                i = 1
                num = 1
                Me.bLastCarriageReturn = False
            End If
            While i < length
                Dim c As Char = Me.sb(i)
                If c = ControlChars.Cr OrElse c = ControlChars.Lf Then
                    If c = ControlChars.Cr AndAlso i + 1 < length AndAlso Me.sb(i + 1) = ControlChars.Lf Then
                        i += 1
                    End If

                    Dim obj As String = Me.sb.ToString(num, i + 1 - num)

                    num = i + 1

                    SyncLock Me.messageQueue
                        Me.messageQueue.Enqueue(obj)
                    End SyncLock
                End If
                i += 1
            End While

            ' Flush Fix: Send Whatever is left in the buffer
            Dim endOfBuffer As String = Me.sb.ToString(num, length - num)
            SyncLock Me.messageQueue
                Me.messageQueue.Enqueue(endOfBuffer)
                num = length
            End SyncLock
            ' End Flush Fix

            If Me.sb(length - 1) = ControlChars.Cr Then
                Me.bLastCarriageReturn = True
            End If
            If num < length Then
                Me.sb.Remove(0, num)
            Else
                Me.sb.Length = 0
            End If
            Me.FlushMessageQueue()
        End Sub
        Private Sub FlushMessageQueue()
            While Me.messageQueue.Count > 0
                SyncLock Me.messageQueue
                    If Me.messageQueue.Count > 0 Then
                        Dim data As String = DirectCast(Me.messageQueue.Dequeue(), String)
                        If Not Me.cancelOperation Then
                            Me.userCallBack(data)
                        End If
                    End If
                    Continue While
                End SyncLock
                Exit While
            End While
        End Sub
        Friend Sub WaitUtilEOF()
            If Me.eofEvent IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.eofEvent.WaitOne()
                Me.eofEvent.Close()
                Me.eofEvent = Nothing
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class DataReceivedEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs
        Friend _data As String
        ''' <summary>Gets the line of characters that was written to a redirected <see cref="T:System.Diagnostics.Process" /> output stream.</summary>
        ''' <returns>The line that was written by an associated <see cref="T:System.Diagnostics.Process" /> to its redirected <see cref="P:System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardOutput" /> or <see cref="P:System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardError" /> stream.</returns>
        ''' <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
        Public ReadOnly Property Data() As String
            Get
                Return Me._data
            End Get
        End Property
        Friend Sub New(ByVal data As String)
            Me._data = data
        End Sub
    End Class






End Module
```

and my Form Code...

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq


Imports System.Collections




Public Class Form3

    ' Define static variables shared by class methods.
    Private Shared shellOutput As StringBuilder = Nothing
    Private Shared numOutputLines As Integer = 0
    Private Shared stdIN As StreamWriter
    Private Shared p As New FixedProcess 'as new
    Private Shared oldOutlineData As String = ""
    Private Shared PasswordInput As Boolean = False



    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ShowISDNStatus()

    End Sub

    Public Sub ShowISDNStatus()
        Dim p_info As New ProcessStartInfo 'as new
        p_info.FileName = Form1.PlinkPath
        p_info.Arguments = Form1.KommandoArguments
        p_info.UseShellExecute = False
        p_info.CreateNoWindow = True
        p_info.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        p_info.RedirectStandardInput = True
        p_info.RedirectStandardError = True
        ' Set our event handler to asynchronously read the shell output.
        AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf dirOutputHandler
        AddHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf dirOutputHandler



        shellOutput = New StringBuilder
        p.StartInfo = p_info
        p.Start()
        p.BeginOutputReadLine()
        p.BeginErrorReadLine()
        stdIN = p.StandardInput

        'stdIN.WriteLine("enable" & vbCr & "K#limdor1" & vbCrLf)
        'Timer1.Enabled = True
        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)

        'stdIN.WriteLine("term len 0")
        'stdIN.WriteLine("show isdn status")

        stdIN.WriteLine("enable" & vbCr & Form1.TextPassword.Text & vbCrLf)
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        Me.TextBox2.Text = ""
        stdIN.WriteLine("term len 0")
        stdIN.WriteLine("show isdn status")
        Me.TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
        Me.TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub dirOutputHandler(ByVal sendingProcess As Object, ByVal outLine As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        ''If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data) Then
        shellOutput.Append(outLine.Data)

        'For i = 1 To Len(outLine.Data)
        '    FormDebug.TextBox1.Text = "Len von OutlineData: " & Len(outLine.Data) & " " & Asc(Mid(outLine.Data, i, 1)) & "---" & Mid(outLine.Data, i, 1)
        'Next

        If outLine.Data = "Store key in cache? (y/n) " Then
            stdIN.WriteLine("y")
        End If

        Form3.TextBox1.Text = outLine.Data

        ''End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



    End Sub

    Private Sub Form3_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing


        p.Kill()



    End Sub


    Private Sub TextBox2_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.PreviewKeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Then

            If PasswordInput = False Then
                If Me.TextBox2.Text = "en" Then
                    Me.TextBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
                    Me.TextBox2.Text = ""
                    PasswordInput = True
                    Timer1.Enabled = False
                    Me.TextBox1.AppendText("Password:")

                ElseIf Me.TextBox2.Text = "ena" Then
                    Me.TextBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
                    Me.TextBox2.Text = ""
                    PasswordInput = True
                    Timer1.Enabled = False
                    Me.TextBox1.AppendText("Password:")

                ElseIf Me.TextBox2.Text = "enab" Then
                    Me.TextBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
                    Me.TextBox2.Text = ""
                    PasswordInput = True
                    Timer1.Enabled = False
                    Me.TextBox1.AppendText("Password:")

                ElseIf Me.TextBox2.Text = "enabl" Then
                    Me.TextBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
                    Me.TextBox2.Text = ""
                    PasswordInput = True
                    Timer1.Enabled = False
                    Me.TextBox1.AppendText("Password:")

                ElseIf Me.TextBox2.Text = "enable" Then
                    Me.TextBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
                    Me.TextBox2.Text = ""
                    PasswordInput = True
                    Timer1.Enabled = False
                    Me.TextBox1.AppendText("Password:")

                ElseIf Me.TextBox2.Text = "" Then
                    stdIN.WriteLine()
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                    Me.TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
                    Me.TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
                Else
                    stdIN.WriteLine(Me.TextBox2.Text)
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                    Me.TextBox2.Text = ""
                    Me.TextBox1.Text = shellOutput.ToString
                    Me.TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
                    Me.TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
                End If

            Else

                stdIN.WriteLine("enable" & vbCr & Me.TextBox2.Text & vbCrLf)
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                Me.TextBox2.Text = ""
                Timer1.Enabled = True
                Me.TextBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = False
                stdIN.WriteLine("term len 0")
                Me.TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
                Me.TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
                PasswordInput = False

            End If


        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Me.TextBox1.SelectAll()
        Me.TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ' If Me.TextBox1.Text <> shellOutput.ToString Then Me.TextBox1.Text = shellOutput.ToString
        Me.TextBox1.Text = shellOutput.ToString

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        FormDebug.Show()
        'Dim frm As New Form3
        'Static Num As Integer

        'Num = Num + 1
        'frm.Text = "Copy of Form3 - " & Num
        'frm.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ...hmm further investigation looks like it should be this:         Public Overridable Sub Close()
            Me.Dispose(True)
        End Sub
Unfortunately it seems to take the system.diagnostics.close instead. I also tried to create a dll in a separate project with the namespace system.diagnostics but even if i add this dll as namespace to my project it still seems to take the original close and not my version...