Set ProcessStartInfo.StandardInputEncoding to UTF8 insert weird character at the start of input?
I have a Winforms application running on .NET 5 (.NET Core) with richTextBox1 to show result & textBox1 to write cmd.
Here is the code:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Process m_proc;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        m_proc = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                ErrorDialog = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,

                //UTF8
                StandardInputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true,
            SynchronizingObject = this
        };

        m_proc.OutputDataReceived += DoEvent_proc_OutputDataReceived;
        m_proc.ErrorDataReceived += DoEvent_proc_ErrorDataReceived;

        m_proc.Start();
        m_proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        m_proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

        textBox1.KeyDown += DoEvent_tbConsole_KeyDown;
    }

    private void DoEvent_proc_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
            richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Concat("====> Error: ", e.Data));
            richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        });
    }

    private void DoEvent_proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
            richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Data);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        });
    }
    private void DoEvent_tbConsole_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;//Clear 'ding' sound

                m_proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);

                textBox1.Clear();
                break;

            case Keys.Escape:
                Close();
                break;
        }
    }
}

When I enter the text "echo test" in textBox1 and press enter, I got the result:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] (c)
2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
E:\net5.0-windows>echo test
====> Error: 'echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
====> Error: operable program or batch file.

'echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, is because the program has insert some unicode text (∩╗┐) before the cmd echo, so the program didn't see it as echo but as ∩╗┐echo. Now if I execute echo test again, it'll work fine because the weird character (∩╗┐) only insert one time at the beginning.
You can see its weird font in Notepad++

Now if I remove the code StandardInputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,:
                ...                    
                //UTF8
                //StandardInputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, //Remove!!!!
                StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                ...

It'll work fine (it won't insert weird character (∩╗┐) anymore)

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] (c)
2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
E:\net5.0-windows>echo test
test

So I see the problem is StandardInputEncoding, I need to set StandardInputEncoding to UTF8 so I can pass unicode characters to my program, but if I do this, then the first cmd always fail (because it inserts weird char at the beginning). I have tried to find a way to clear input at the beginning to clear that weird char, but look like it doesn't have any function to do that, I tried to send Esc key to clear that weird char but still doesn't work. I wonder why it inserts the weird char in the first place? (.NET Core bug?). How can I fix this?

Those character look like the Byte Order Mark in whatever encoding your cmd understands actually. Try using new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false); instead of System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

And presumably you not to change the cmd encoding itself to something utf-8 compatible with for example a chcp 65001 call to use the utf-8 codepage.

Definitely byte order marks. Can't you use the standard Unicode encoding? -- (unrelated) Why are you Invoking when you have set the SynchronizingObject? Also unrelated, when you set e.SuppressKeyPress you don't need to set e.Handled -- EnableRaisingEvents is only related to the Exited event

Thank @Ralf , your comment is the solution, thank you very much. I've posted the answer to help future visitors.

@Jimi about SynchronizingObject, I just learned from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11675360/4608491 , it worked so I just leave it, hehe. Thanks for the e.Handled tip.

The SynchronizingObject is tested for null in one of the snippets in that Q&A, because a helper class, instantiated by a user, may or may not set it. If you set it yourself beforehand, then you should (really) not invoke. That's the whole point of specifying a SynchronizingObject (there's more to it, but let's leave it at that)

@Ralf - about chcp 65001, I didn't use that bc I heard it's dangerous to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843552/4608491 https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131654/4608491

@123iamking "about chcp 65001, I didn't use that bc I heard it's dangerous to use" - ridiculous! Read and follow UTF-8 Everywhere…

Thanks to @Ralf, the solution is: replace System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 with new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false)
So the code should be:
...
//UTF8
//StandardInputEncoding can't be System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, bc of Byte Order Mark bug
StandardInputEncoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false),
StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
...


Its not a bug it is just the well defined default behavior according to the documentation that most of the time fits just not in this use case.

@Ralf : Thank Ralf. I mean the bug of my program (bug that make the first cmd always fails, but I named it "Byte Order Mark" for the reminder of the cause of the bug), not the bug of the .NET Core.
