# Redirect process output C#

Tags: c#, process, redirectstandardoutput, output-redirect

I would like to redirect the Process's standard output to a string for later parsing.
I would also like to see the output on the screen, while the process is running, and not only when it finishes it's run.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Please provide more detail on what actually you are trying to do

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# get process output while running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994610/c-sharp-get-process-output-while-running)

Comment: I think the following are also relevant. [c# - ProcessStartInfo hanging on "WaitForExit"? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why)
 - [c# - Best way to interact with Command Line application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442680/best-way-to-interact-with-command-line-application)
 - [C# : Redirect console application output : How to flush the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033648/c-sharp-redirect-console-application-output-how-to-flush-the-output)

Comment: But wait, there are more: [redirect - C# - Realtime console output redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501511/c-sharp-realtime-console-output-redirection")
 - [c# - How can I redirect process output (console) to richtextbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521475/how-can-i-redirect-process-output-console-to-richtextbox")
 - [c# - StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160187/standardoutput-readtoend-hangs")

Answer (score 27):

Use [`RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx).

Sample from MSDN:

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
p.Start();
// Do not wait for the child process to exit before
// reading to the end of its redirected stream.
// p.WaitForExit();
// Read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Also see [`OutputDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) and [`BeginOutputReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx) for an alternative to `ReadToEnd()`, that will better fulfill your "see output while the process is running" requirement.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to execute an exe from your c# application and get the output from it then you can use the below code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();            

p.StartInfo.FileName = "PATH TO YOUR FILE";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = metalType + " " + graphHeight + " " + graphWidth;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;              

p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Start();            
svgText = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

using(StreamReader s = p.StandardError)
{
    string error = s.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit(20000);
}
```

Don't forgete to write p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

Comment: `EnableRaisingEvents` is only needed for the `Process.Exited` event.