# Synchronously reading stdout of a process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process

I am executing an exe file which contains some c code from my c# winform but I get the complete output of the c code only after the complete execution of exe. I want the exe to relay its output to my winform synchronously (line by line in realtime).

```
    var proc = new Process
      {
          StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
          {
              FileName = "background.exe",
              Arguments = command,
              UseShellExecute = false,
              RedirectStandardOutput = true,
              CreateNoWindow = true
          }
      };


      proc.Start();
      while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
      {
          ConsoleWindow.AppendText(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
          ConsoleWindow.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

      }
```

Comment: What do you mean `some c code`? No text gets written to output unless the executing *process* put it there. You should check the code of `background.exe`. And make sure that `background.exe` is actually a compiled, binary executable file and not just a C file with a different extension

Comment: Did you checked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net) and this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588659/redirect-process-output-c-sharp) ?

Comment: Checked all the code examples and they read the output only after the process is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which is loosely adapted from [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var consoleProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName =
                    @"background.exe",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            }
        };

        consoleProcess.OutputDataReceived += ConsoleOutputHandler;
        consoleProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        consoleProcess.Start();
        consoleProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }

    private void ConsoleOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,
        DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        // This is the method in your form that's 
        // going to display the line of output from the console.
        WriteToOutput(outLine.Data);
    }
```

Note that the event handler that receives the output from the console is executing on a different thread, so you have to ensure that whatever you use to display the output on your form occurs on the UI thread.

Comment: Isn't `BeginOutputReadLine` an asynchronous method?

Comment: No, not in the sense of async methods that return `Task`. It begins an async operation. But it is not an async method.