# control cmd.exe with c# (send and read outputs)

Tags: c#, cmd

I want to send and receive commands like "dir" and so on but i can't manage to read the output

Comment: code please.  Did you look at the Process class and other questions on SO related to reading output from it?

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer you found most helpful.  This will ensure that you get help in the future.

Comment: when i try to "thank" someone i get
"You can't vote for your own post."
i think it's cuz i'm new here

Comment: There is a check mark that appears to the left of each person's answer.  To accept an answer, click the one next to the answer you found most helpful.

Comment: oh dear god how i missed it -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to execute an external application and capture the output you should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415620/redirect-console-output-to-textbox-in-separate-program-c). The [System.IO namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) has Directory, File, and Path classed which avoid the need to use external applications to enumerate directories.

Answer (score 3):

You have to redirect std in and std out.  Once you do that, in C#, use the console as you would if you were writing a console app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x859hf2(vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should not use console commands from code unless you *really* need to.  (Hint: You don't)

You're looking for [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx).