# Is it possible to display a command window inside a windows form?

Tags: .net, winforms, command-line

Instead of spawning a separate command window as a child window, is it possible to host a command console as a child control of a form?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to display the *actual* console window inside a form, but you can redirect the output of the console to your app and display it in your own control.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415620/redirect-console-output-to-textbox-in-separate-program-c) which has some examples. Also on MSDN I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx).