# Get output of PHP script from C#

Tags: c#, php

I was wondering if it is possible to get the HTML output of a PHP file using a C# Windows application.
I have already googled for this, but all I could find was a compiler where you could use PHP together with C#.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: If you mean local php script then you can execute php.exe passing as command line arg script file name, .net provides features to execute external applications as start process

Comment: do you mean get the html out of a php source file or have php evaluate the php file and get the resulting html? You might have problems with the latter simply because of plugins/external (e.g. db) connections.

Comment: Maybe you can use [Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/) in some way?

Comment: use this http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx routine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HttpWebRequest - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx to get the HTML.

As everyone is suggesting to get output of local script: look into `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` and related functions to run from command line. You can either dump output to file first and than read it with C# or redirect output (i.e.  [C# - Realtime console output redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501511/c-realtime-console-output-redirection) )

Comment: Yes, but I would like to get the output of a local php file.

Comment: Then you will need to run the script yourself using the interpreter, @Jerodev

Comment: if that's the case, your option with C# is simulate how you would do it from the command line - i.e. launch a process that is the php compiler.