# Cmd not elevating when redirecting input/output

Tags: c#, wpf, cmd

I'm trying to run automated installations via CMD commands. The programs output progress and I need to capture that output and calculate total progress in a nice window. In my understanding it is impossible to elevate and redirect at the same time. I've tried...

Running cmd elevated and feeding it commands.

```
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Verb = "runas",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();
        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("command");
```

Running cmd with command as an argument

```
            var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = "/C " + "command",
                    Verb = "runas",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
```

To no effect. Is there any tricks to this? Elevating after input/output has been captured? I need this to work. Would this be possible with psexec?

Comment: You're trying to run automated installations via a batch program which displays output, capture the output and display in real time... Sorry but why not just rewrite the commands to run via your WPF? In any case, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4501659/612717)

Answer (score 0):

If you own the installer programs, you can rewrite them so that they do not use standard streams as a means of communication, but for example [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762927(v=vs.110).aspx). If you don't, you can write a wrapper program that runs elevated (you run it with `UseShellExecute`), does not use the standard streams, but runs the installer programs and redirects their input (you run them without `UseShellExecute`) reporting progress to the nonelevated main program via named pipes or some other means. I hope this diagram makes it clearer:

```
non-elevated.exe
    \
     \ named pipes
      \
elevated-wrapper.exe (ran with UseShellExecute=true)
        \
         \ redirected standard streams
          \
installer-program.exe (ran with UseShellExecute=false and redirected streams)
```