# Redirecting Command output to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am running sDelete64.exe inside a WinForms application.  I redirect it's output to a textbox.  However, only the first line of the output is redirected.  What sDelete displays if you run it normally is

```
sDelete is set for 1 pass.
Zeroing free space on C:\: 0%
```

When I redirect it I only get the first line.  If I redirect a command like dir, no problem I get everything back.

```
    private bool ExecuteCmd(string command)
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        {
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Arguments = "/c " + command
        };


        _process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
        Logger.Debug(string.Format("Cmd.exe is Launching command {0}", command));
        _process.Start();

        _process.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                Logger.Debug("Updating loading panel with {0}", e.Data);
                _textBox.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";

            }

        };

        _process.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                Logger.Debug("Updating loading panel with {0}", e.Data);
                _textBox.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";

            }

        };

        _process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        _process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        _process.WaitForExit();

        return _process.HasExited;
```

What could cause sDelete's StandardOutput not be captured?

Comment: First, it seems odd to call Start() before assigning the event handlers.  Not sure it matters here or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really I found the answer here.  Creating a process that will continually read from the StandardOutput Stream and update a StreamWriter.

[C# - Realtime console output redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501511/c-sharp-realtime-console-output-redirection?noredirect=1&lq=1)