# c# coding convention public/private contexts

Tags: c#, winforms, conventions

I'm learning C# and I'm creating a simple WinForms application, and what it does is starting a simple OpenVPN client:

```
    void button_Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c openvpn.exe --config config.ovpn --auto-proxy";

        // set up output redirection
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        // Input
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        // Other
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        // see below for output handler
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;

        proc.Start();

        StreamWriter myStreamWriter = proc.StandardInput;
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

        proc.WaitForExit();
    }

    void proc_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // output will be in string e.Data
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            string Data = e.Data.ToString();
            if (Data.Contains("Enter Auth Username"))
            {
                myStreamWriter("myusername");
            }
            //MessageBox.Show(Data);
        }
    }
```

What it does now, is send all the output of the CMD to my program, which run commands depending on the output.

My current issue is, I need to write to the stream. I use `myStreamWriter` in `proc_DataReceived`, however it's not in the same context so it doesn't work.

I get the following error: `The name 'myStreamWriter' does not exist in the current context`, which is obviously non existent in that scope.

How do I make this work? Get/set properties? Like I said I'm quite new to C# so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for the word "scope" and not "context" ;).

Comment: Why are you starting `cmd.exe` and not just `openvpn.exe`?

Comment: @tomfanning Because I need to write to the cmd process. It didn't work when just opening `openvpn.exe`.

Comment: @Devator What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it throw a null reference error?

Comment: @Devator, thats because you've set `UseShellExecute` to `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form, add this field:

```
public class Form1Whatevver: Form {
    private StreamWriter myStreamWriter;
}
```

Then in your code:

```
proc.Start();

this.myStreamWriter = proc.StandardInput;

proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Now, myStreamWriter will be available to `proc_DataReceived()`

```
void proc_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // output will be in string e.Data
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            string Data = e.Data.ToString();
            if (Data.Contains("Enter Auth Username"))
            {
                if (myStreamWriter != null) // Just in case
                {
                    myStreamWriter("myusername");
                }
            }
            //MessageBox.Show(Data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are talking about is [Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) not context.

---

The are several ways you could alter your code so that you can access `myStreamWriter` from `proc_DataReceived`.

Arguably the simplest, is to pass the object you wish to effect as a parameter to the function. This is often a good approach in the perspective of future multi-threading and a drive towards a functional style.

```
    void proc_DataReceived(
        object sender, 
        DataReceivedEventArgs e,
        StreamWriter writer)
    {
        ...
        writer("myusername");
        ...
    }
```

However `proc_DataReceived` is obviously an event handler and you probably don't want to change the signature of the function.

---

If you declare `myStreamWriter` as a Private Member Variable at the class level you will be able to access from anywhere within the class. The `this` is optional but good form.

```
class YourForm : Form
{
    private StreamWriter myStreamWriter;

    void button_Connect_Click(...
    {
        ...
        this.myStreamWriter = proc.StandardInput;
        ...
    }

    void proc_DataRecieved(...
    {
        ...
        this.myStreamWriter("myusername");
        ...

    }
}
```

---

A property implementation is not necessary unless you want to access the `StreamWriter` from outside the class/form.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not the answer I need. I've added my error: `The name 'myStreamWriter' does not exist in the current context`. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: -1 this isn't an answer and there is already a comment about this.

Comment: @Devator I've written my answer in several stages, is this more agreeable?

Comment: @juharr I've finished writing my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

The simple quick-fix is to define `myStreamWriter` as a field in the class (i.e. outside the scopes of your methods), then instantiate it from within one of the scopes:

```
private StreamWriter _myStreamWriter;

void button_Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do some stuff

    _myStreamWriter = proc.StandardInput;

    // Do some stuff
}
```

Having done that should let you use it wherever you want within the class.