# C# - Capturing Windows Application Output

Tags: c#, .net, windows

My application launches "C:\Windows\System32\Msra.Exe" to control a domaincomputer. Is there a way I can capture the error messages that this msra.Exe shows. (I.e. internal error messages from the msra.exe and not the ones from my app.)
The app itself is a windows Forms app.

Any help is appreciated.

The Code to start MSRA is below... it is just a snippet of the complete application.

```
string msra = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\runas.exe";

string domainname = "**********";
string domaincontroller = "*************";

if (File.Exists(msra) == false)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Runas.exe not found.\n\rPlease contact your internal IT support.", "Fatal Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
else
{
    try
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = msra;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/noprofile /netonly /user:" + domainname + "\\" + username + " \"cmd /server:" + domaincontroller + " /C msra.exe /offerra " + computerip + "\"";
        p.Start();
        p.Dispose();
        Thread.Sleep(1700);
        SendKeys.SendWait(password);
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
    }
    catch
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("MSRA could not be started for an unknown reason");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect console output to textbox in separate program C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415620/redirect-console-output-to-textbox-in-separate-program-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `RedirectStandardOutput` or `RedirectStandardError` to `true` to be able to read from the standard output or error output of the process.

You then have several options how to actually read the data:

- use `StandardOutput` property
- subsribe to the `OutputDataReceived` event and call `BeginOutputReadLine()`

Or the corresponding members for the error stream.

Comment: Thanks - This is indeed the way to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx

[Updated to point to a .net example]

Answer (score 1):

You are using Process so try the Process.StandardError property. You assign it a stream and you will be able to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx

And while you're there you can also use Process.StandardOutput

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx

Comment: Thanks - This is indeed the way to proceed.