# Running cmd commands and getting results to a string variable

Tags: c++, cmd

How to run a cmd command, and getting the output to a string variable?
Example:

```
string result = ExecuteFunction("ipconfig");
```

Now "result" contains:

```
Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
......
```

This shuld be happening without showing any cmd screen, all from the program.
Windows platform of course.

Comment: Is the C++ tag correct? It looks more like C#. Context would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a pipe:

On Linux:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    FILE* fp = popen("ifconfig", "r");
    if(fp) {
        std::vector<char> buffer(4096);
        std::size_t n = fread(buffer.data(), 1, buffer.size(), fp);
        if(n && n < buffer.size()) {
            buffer.data()[n] = 0;
            std::cout << buffer.data() << '\n';
        }
        pclose(fp);
    }
}
```

For Windows you might use '_popen' and change 'ifconfig' to 'ipconfig'

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution for this problem since time immemorial is to use command line redirection to send standard output to a text file, and then read the file into a string.

You didn't provide enough context to respond with code. In C/C++ you could use _popen(). In .NET this answer might help.
[Redirect console output to textbox in separate program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415620/redirect-console-output-to-textbox-in-separate-program-c-sharp)

Comment: Hardly the standard solution. The standard solution would be to send standard output to a pipe and read that. No need to hit the file system.

Comment: No, that solution only applies down the Unix/C branch of history. In the MSDOS/Windows 3/VB/Access branch pipes were not available, but command line redirection was. I guess this is the problem with answering questions that don't provide enough context.