# Running EXE file form CMD made with C#

Tags: c#, cmd, exe, argument-passing

I'm newbie in c# and I'm stuck on this conundrum
I've recently made a Gui Program in c# that include several tabs and some other stuff 
Now I want to make one of the tabs as a exe file that i would be able to run via cmd .
the entire code i want to put in file is comprised of one class 
something like that

```
class E2p
{
main program( take 2 arg )
{some Code


make a CSV file in appDirectory
}
```

I want to turn it to EXE file so I can run it from CMD like that

```
E2pChck.exe -i 10.0.0.127 -r RandomWord
```

How can I do it ??

Comment: Why not create a new project, a Windows Console application, that does that? Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you need to *intercept* the output of the other program?. If so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415620/redirect-console-output-to-textbox-in-separate-program-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after, but I think you mean that you want to be able to run your exe from the command line with a couple of arguments.

These arguments are passed into your application in the `Main` method, which you'll find in Program.cs. In a command line application the arguments parameter is provided for you, but you can add it to a Windows Forms application.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string firstArgument;
        string secondArgument;
        const int NumberOfArgumentsRequired = 2;

        // you can access the arguments using the args array, 
        // but we need to make sure we have enough arguments, 
        // otherwise we'll get an index out of range exception 
        // (as we're trying to access items in an array that aren't there)
        if (args.Length >= NumberOfArgumentsRequired)
        {
            firstArgument = args[0];
            secondArgument = args[1];
        }
        else
        {
            // this block will be called if there weren't enough arguments
            // it's useful for setting defaults, although that could also be done
            // at the point where the strings were declared
            firstArgument = "This value was set because there weren't enough arguments.";
            secondArgument = "So was this one. You could do this at the point of declaration instead, if you wish.";
        }

        string outputString = string.Format("This is the first: {0}\r\nAnd this is the second: {1}", firstArgument, secondArgument);
        Console.WriteLine(outputString);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If you typed `E2pChck.exe -i 10.0.0.127 -r RandomWord` into the command line then:

```
args[0] would be "-i"
args[1] would be "10.0.0.127"
args[2] would be "-r"
args[3] would be "RandomWord"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't technically answer the question, but the OP asked for an example of starting a process.

You would put this code in your button handler (probably on a separate thread so your UI doesn't hang)

```
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo csvGenerationProcInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    csvGenerationProcInfo.Arguments = "-i 10.0.0.127 -r RandomWord";
    csvGenerationProcInfo.FileName = "E2pChck.exe";

    System.Diagnostics.Process csvGenerationProc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(csvGenerationProcInfo);
    csvGenerationProc.WaitForExit();
```

Or, if you don't need all the features of ProcessStartInfo you can just use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("E2pChck.exe", "-i 10.0.0.127 -r RandomWord");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think you mean you wouldn't put this in your button handler.

Comment: Well, you could start the thread in the button handler, but yes, you wouldn't want to lock the UI while waiting for a process to finish. Thank you for clarifying.