# Get the result of executing telnet with result

Tags: c#, telnet, system.diagnostics

I want to telnet to ip address in c# and I used process,how can I get the result if the telnet to that port is successful?

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415620/redirect-console-output-to-textbox-in-separate-program.

Comment: Don't use a process.  Don't use redirection, it doesn't work for telnet.exe due to its need to emulate a terminal.  Telnet is a very simple protocol, just use a TcpClient for port 23.